# How to send a nested map from server to client using jsonrpc package in golang?

Tags: go

I am writing a client server go application which uses yahoo finance api to fetch the real time stock price. I am using jsonrpc package to connect client and server.
I am unable to pass a nested map response from server to client. Here is my small snippet from the client file.  client.go file

```
var (
        reply map[string]map[int]float64
    )

    c := jsonrpc.NewClient(client)
    err = c.Call("JSONResponse.GetStockValue", args, &reply)
    fmt.Println(reply)
```

Server file looks like this:

```
func (j *JSONResponse) GetStockValue(args *ClientRequest, reply *map[string]map[int]float64) error {
 some piece of code......
 nestedMap := make(map[string]map[int]float64)
 add some values in nested map .....
 fmt.Println(nestedMap)
 *reply = nestedMap
  return nil
}
```

This does not send any response to the client. When i change the nested map to simple map like map[string]int, it correctly works. The nested map is correctly displayed at server but does not get displayed on the client side. The client simply keeps on waiting for the response from the server. It would be very helpful if someone could guide me on why it is not accepting a nested map and working fine for a simple map ?

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know why this is behaving like this but when i changed the type of nested map from m[string]map[int]float64 to map[string]map[string]string it worked for me. Could someone please explain me why ?

Comment: Unrelated, you should return `nestedMap` from `GetStockValue()` than changing the value of of `reply` which is a global variable (bad practice).

Answer (score 1):

`jsonrpc` is `json rpc` because it use `json` for serialization. to Marshal a map to `json`, you need `string` key type. refer to [encoding/json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)

Answer (score 0):

If you print out your `err` here `err = c.Call("JSONResponse.GetStockValue", args, &reply)` you should see the reason `invalid character '' looking for beginning of object key string.`

The [JSON spec](http://json.org/) says the object's key needs to be `string`.

Or if you JSON is using `string`, then `json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type map[int]float64`